# WebDeploy: merge content

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

I have 2 builds (in TeamCity):

One that produces a backend for a website, with WebAPI.

I package that website with WebDeploy as such:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile="Default" /p:ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled=False`

Which delivers me a nice WebDeploy.zip

Now I have a second build, which builds and compiles a website frontend.

Frontend and backend are being developed by different teams, and thus produce artifacts at different times.

I want to be able to deploy a version of the backend with the frontend merged in.

Now I have 2 options, either rebuild the backend with a dependency to the frontend (which creates a new unneeded build), or something else (which is what I really want).

I want to, given a web deploy package, merge in the files of the frontend, deploy the website to IIS.

Now I can manually unzip the webdeploy package and rebuild it by hand. However the paths in there are based on the paths of the location that it is built at (and I have no control over that).

Example: `C_C\TeamCity\...blabla...\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config`

Which makes it hard to find out the structure without parsing the `archive.xml` found at the root of the WebDeploy package.

It is possible, but ideally I would like an MSBuild command that would allow me to 'merge' the contents of a directory into this website.

**Question:**

1. Is this possible with MSDeploy?
2. If that is not possible, is it possible to change the directory naming insite the WebDeploy package, to have something more straightforward, for when I want to inject the additional files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deploy the package to a local directory using the [dirPath](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207412%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) provider, add your files and then repackage.  First you need to create a destination manifest because WebDeploy creates the package with a source manifest.  You can create a "DestManifest.xml" file with following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <dirPath path="c:\repackagewebdeploy" />
  <auto />
  <auto />
</sitemanifest>
```

Then you can call MSDeploy to unpackage and repackage.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\packagePath\package.zip -dest:manifest=[path to destination manifest]
[copy files]
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:dirPath=c:\repackagewebdeploy -dest:package=c:\packagePath\newPackage.zip
```

This assumes you don't need the other setAcl providers.  We don't typically need these so I ignore them but you could add them back into the final package using a manifest instead of pulling using the dirPath directly.

Comment: Unfortunately the provider `package` is not compatible with the provider `dirPath`. 
`Error: Source (sitemanifest) and destination (dirPath) are not compatible for the given operation.
Error count: 1.`

Comment: Yeah, forgot about the manifest.  I updated my answer to account for the manifest and tested it so I know it works this time.  Please let me know if you have any other issues.